# REGEX: DOS FindStr Command Has No Inverse Class Capability?

Tags: regex, windows

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459%28WS.10%29.aspx) says that FindStr handles inverse class syntax, such as finding any character that does not match 'X':

```
[^X]
```

But a few simple tests show this is not the case - at least not on my Windows 7 x64 setup.  Findstr treats the inverse class notation '^' as if it is not there at all.  So it sees the above regex as this:

```
[X]
```

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to trick FindStr to recognize the '^' inverse class notation?

Yes I could use a different tool besides FindStr, but that is often the tool already installed on a Windows setup.

Comment: ^ is a command line metacharacter so you need to quote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` is the escape character in `cmd.exe`. You must escape it (analoguous to `\` in other environments). Try:

```
[^^X]
```

Comment: I tried all options on command `dir /b %windir%\ | findstr "[^w]"` to exclude all the files containing "w" letter.  `[^w]` works like `[w]`, and `[^^w]`, `"[^w]"`, `"[^^w]"` do not work at all (no list filtering). Win7. Seems the only way is to build positive matching expression and invert results with `/v` switch.

Answer (score 1):

Are you enclosing the search expression in double quotes? IIRC an unquoted `^` will simply quote the next character literally, which sounds like what you are reporting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, that works:

```
echo 123|findstr /R "[^0-9]"
```

finds nothing as expected.

The same without quotes does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately you're wrong. Try `echo 123|findstr /R "[^0]"`.

Answer (score 0):

Run some tests to make the behaviour of findstr clearer. The test don't cover all possibilities, but just to make a start:

```
echo.123|findstr.exe /x /r "[^0]" 
echo.123|findstr.exe /x /r "[^0][0-9]" 
echo.123|findstr.exe /b /r "[^0][0-9]*" 
echo. 123|findstr.exe /b /r "[^0][0-9]*" 
echo.123a|findstr.exe /b /r "[^0][0-9]*" 
echo.123a|findstr.exe /r "^[^0][0-9]*" 
echo.123a|findstr.exe /r "^[0][0-9]*$" 
echo.123a|findstr.exe /r "[^0]$" 
echo.123a|findstr.exe /r "[^a]$" 
echo.123a|findstr.exe /e /r "[^a]" 
echo.123a|findstr.exe /b /r "[^a]"
```

More than one regular expression between the quotes is possible. Findstr will search for both expressions (using or relationship).